# Yii2 виджет выполнить метод

Tags: yii2

Сделал виджет, отображает список пользователей в зависимости от переданных параметров (страна, место жительства и т.д.) из класса виджета делаю рендер
view и все как бы отлично, но стал опрос обновлять список пользователей с другими
параметрами,то есть вызвать метод скажем - Update, что бы список перестроился, возможно ли это?

Правки от 10-08
Код вьюшки:

```
<?php 
use yii\helpers\HTML;
use yii\widgets\Pjax;
use app\models\desire;

$model=new desire();
$a_rows=$model->get_desire_for_search_page($user_id,$status,$category);

?>

<?php Pjax::begin(); ?>
<a id="a_pjax" href="/profile/search-desires?user_id=0&status=0&category=0" style="/*display:none;*/">Обновить</a>
<ul class="init_content">
<?php 
    foreach ($a_rows as $desire)
    {
        $fname=$desire["fname"];
        if($fname=="")
        {
            $fname="/css/img/ico_event_family.svg";
    }
        $name=HTML::encode($desire["name"]);
        $komm=mb_substr(strip_tags(HTML::decode($desire["komm"])),0,140)."...";
        $dt= get_normal_date($desire["dt_add"]);
        $dt_end= get_normal_date($desire["dt_end"]);
        $id=$desire["id"];
        $url="/profile/desire/show?id=$id";
?>        
                <li id="desire_list_li_<?php echo $id?>">
            <div class="desirebox">
                <div class="desirebox_left">
                                    <a href="<?php echo $url ?>"><img src="<?php echo $fname ?>" width="90" height="90" alt=""/></a>
                </div>
                <div class="desirebox_right">
                                    <a href="<?php echo $url ?>" class="eventbox_th"><?php echo $name ?></a>
                                    <div class="desirebox_target"><?php echo $komm ?></div>
                                    <div class="desirebox_period">Период: с <?php echo $dt ?> по <?php echo $dt_end ?></div>
                    <div class="event_editbox">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="check_desire_close(<?php echo $id?>);" title="Отметить сбышемся"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i></a>
                                                <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="del_desire(<?php echo $id?>,'<?php echo $name ?>')" title="Удвлить"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
                        <a href="/profile/desire/edit?id=<?php echo $id?>" title="Редактировать"><i class="fa fa-gear"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
<?php       
    }
?>
</ul>
<?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

Код контролера:

```
public function actionSearchDesires($user_id,$status,$category)
{   
    //проверяем авторизован юзер или нет
    if ($_SESSION["user_login"] == 0) {
        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', "Вы не авторизованы на портале!");
        return $this->redirect(['/star/index']);
    }

    if($status==0)
    {
        $status=""; 
    }

    if($status==1)
    {
        $status=" and flg_close=0 ";    
    }

    if($status==2)
    {
        $status=" and flg_close=1 ";
    }

    $this->view->params['user_edit'] = 1;            
    \Yii::$app->view->params['desire_proces'] = 1;
    \Yii::$app->view->params['desire_edit']=1;

    return $this->render('search_desire_widget', [
        'user_id' => $user_id,'status'=>$status, 'category'=>$category
    ]);   
}
```

Вот так вызывается:

```
//передаем во вью массив
$model=new desire();
$a_rows=$model->get_desire_for_search_page(Yii::$app->userrows->get("id"),0,0);

echo $this->render('search_desire_widget', [
    'a_rows' => $a_rows,
    'user_id'=>Yii::$app->userrows->get("id"),
    'status' => 0,
    'category' => 0,
]);
```

Comment: я так понимаю делать это надо через ajax, выполнить запрос ajax и получить по условиям новый блок с данными, и заменить старый блок на новый, тогда вопрос в другом - как вызвать js функцию в виджете?

Comment: Есть же поддержка Pjax. Можно сгенерировать CRUD с поддержкой Pjax и посмотреть как работает.

Comment: Спасибо, yjc сильно сложно и долго... котроллер, pjax, задача сложная, вывод юзеров из базы их отметка, потом для каждого раздела свои условия

Comment: Сделал на jquery+ajax, намного быстрее

Comment: Это прям как чукча на лесоповале пилу дружбу не заводил, а прям так пилил. Смысл тогда использовать Yii? И ничего тут сложного нету. Контроллер есть, добавить экшн, модель есть с правилами.

Comment: Мне нужна возможность обновлять выборку, без перезагрузки
Таких примеров я не нашел, здесь тоже никто не ответил. Есть такой принцип "бритва Окама" посмотрите что означает.  
В  каких то вещах  Yii2 чрезмерен.

Comment: Тут никто не ответил скорее потому, что вопрос не совсем ясен и нет примеров кода. Если речь идет о стандартном списке с фильтрацией и сортировкой, то непонятно в чем проблема. Это все есть из коробки. По поводу Лезвия Оккама, как раз применение jQuery+ajax это вариант, который использует больше ресурсов. Вот простой пример https://nix-tips.ru/examples/yii2pjax/index Контроллер может возвращать вьюшку, в которой рендерится виджет.

Comment: Речь шла о виджете - есть ли у них методы и можно ли их вызвать, что бы обновить view, тоесть вопрос только о виджете. Вот на этот простой вопрос я не получил ответа.

Comment: После отрисовки страницы, при необходимости обновления данных, в любом случае запрос слать на экшн контроллера. А в таком случае достаточно просто отрисовать виджет с новыми параметрами и необходимость в update-методе отпадает.

Comment: Еще раз, может я чего не понимаю или не так обясняю.
Есть виджет виджет1 у него есть - класс и вью
на странице в форме я вывожу этот виджет:
<?php 
echo \app\widgets\UserWidget::widget(array(
    'params'=>[
        'user_id'=>65,
        'flg_checked'=>0
    ]
));
 ?>
так вот, могу ли я вызвать метод у этого?

Comment: Метод можно вызвать, на то он и метод. Но если возникает такая необходимость, вероятно, что-то пошло не так. Предполагаю, что суть виджета в том, чтобы задать ему настройки и он отдал контент. Если надо обновить контент, мы снова вызываем виджет, но уже с другими настройками. Добавь в вопрос код контроллера, вьюшки и виджета, я попробую написать ответ более подробно.

Comment: Вы совершенно правы, я просто не знаю как это реализовать и подумал что есть метод какой инициализаии(обновления), подскажите как еще раз вызвать виджет? во вью он прописан так:
<?php 
echo \app\widgets\UserWidget::widget(array(
    'params'=>[
        'user_id'=>65,
        'flg_checked'=>0
    ]
));
 ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Постараюсь ответить так, как это сделал бы я.

Есть у нас контроллер с действиями. Одно действие отрисовывает вьюшку для страницы, второе действие отдает только контент, который отрисовывает виджет с указанными параметрами.

```
public function actionPage()
{
    $dataProvider = ...;

    return $this->render('page', [
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'id' => $id,
        'checked' => $checked,
    ]);
}

public function actionReloadWidget($id, $checked)
{
    return $this->render('widget', [
        'id' => $id,
        'checked' => $checked,
    ]);
}
```

Далее во вьюшке page выводим нужный контент и вторую вьюшку, которая отрисовывает контент виджета

```
bla bla content

<?= $this->render('widget', [
    'id' => $id,
    'checked' => $checked,
])?>

bla bla content
```

А во вьюшке widget уже вызываем виджет, который примет параметры и отрисует необходимый контент.

```
<?php Pjax::begin(); ?>
<?= Html::a("Update widget", ['site/reload-widget'], ['class' => 'btn btn-lg btn-primary']) ?>
<div class="">
    <?= \app\widgets\UserWidget::widget([
        'params' => [
            'id' => $id,
            'checked' => $checked,
        ]
    ])?>
</div>
<?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

Получается, что когда мы заходим на страницу site/page, то вьюшка вьюшку отрисует, а когда клацаем на кнопку, то запрос уходит на site/reload-widget и тянет контент из вьюшки, в которой лежит только сам виджет UserWidget. Контент обновится в том месте, которое мы обернули в Pjax.

Не забываем из экшеном передать данные во вьюшку для виджета. Реализация может не самая удачная, но я хотел показать лишь механизм. Если данные для настройки виджета надо передавать со страницы, то внутрь Pjax можно добавить форму с инпутами и через них передать данные. [Тут есть примеры с Pjax](https://p0vidl0.info/yii2-vnikaem-v-pjax.html).

**UP 10.08.18**

В таком коде легко можно запутаться.

1. Не создавай во вьюшке модель. Сделай это в контроллере, получи массив и передай во вьюшку. Вьюшка только отрисовывает готовые данные.
2. Ссылки делай через `Url::to(['/controller/action', 'foo' => 'bar'])`, сам себе спасибо скажешь.
3. Если подрезать строку `\yii\helpers\StringHelper::truncate($body,300,'...');`
4. Если выводишь список, почему бы не использовать виджет ListView?
5. Авторизацию проверяй через AccessControl, добавив его в behaviors в контроллере. Или так будешь в каждом экшене одно и то же писать?
6. Череду ифов из экшена убирай в модель или в сервис (хелпер). Экшн контроллера получил данные, передал их вьюшке и все.
7. Когда я вижу `$status=" and flg_close=0 ";`, я понимаю, что дело плохо.

Это для встряски, чтоб не расслаблялся. Сейчас сложно разобраться, что и как происходит, поэтому предлагаю сделать это поэтапно.Сделай в этом же контроллере два чистых экшена и две вьюшки для них (как я выше описал). Сделай временный массив с данными и передай его из экшена во вьюшку, а там разбери на список. А во втором экшене, который должен обновлять, сделай другой массив и тоже передай во вьюшку.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Я просто думал что в виджете класс играет роль контроллера, а можно оказывается по другому.
Теперь стало понятно куда копать)

Comment: Оказалось все не так просо или я опять чето напортачил.
Если я передаю во вью виджета массив с пользователями, все нормально, а вот когда я начинаю их выводить, сразу идет перезагрузка, страница перегружается на адрес акшина и там уже идет отрисовка .
Если просо распечатываю массив,тоже все прекрасно. Могу сбросить вывод, но там ничего особенного <ul> запонянься <li> в <li> вывод данных пользователя, эзерпик, ФИО и ссылка на открытие полного профиля. Может кто то подскаже как работать с выводом в pjax&

Comment: Добавь в вопрос код контроллера и код вьюшек. Может из-за ссылки на профиль?

Comment: Добавил, посмотри плиз я реально задолбался прочитал здесь еще такие же посты, советуют добавить 'linkSelector' => '#a_pjax'
, помогает также не всем. Получается динамический контент нельзя через Pjax делать?

Comment: Обновил ответ. Попробуй сделать все на чистых данных, без лишнего. А потом потихонечку добавишь ссылки, кнопки, картинки. Сначала добейся, чтобы алгоритм с обновлением отрабатывал как положено.

Comment: Ок, щас займусь.

Comment: Сделал чистый экшн и во вью просто вывод числа рандомом от 1 до 10
работает на ура, числа обновляются, все класс. Буду подключать дальше

Comment: Массив передал вывел вардампом, отображается, завтра уже продолжу вывод

Comment: в общем по шагам делал и проблема оказалась в хелпере HTML
$name=HTML::encode($desire["name"]); - если удалить вызов, то все работает. Уж не знаю как это влияет на работу виджета, но без него работает отлично

Comment: Замечания твои учту, спасибо. ЛистВью не подходит, это ж часть выборки есть и круче и здесь будут еще низпадающие панели, удобнее свой написат, за все остальное еще раз спасибо!